# Second order Differential Equation system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Second order system DE
$$\tag 1 x_1''=k(x_2-2x_1) $$
$$\tag 2 x_2''=k(x_1-2x_2+x_3)$$
$$\tag 3 x_3''=k(x_2-2x_3)$$
With $\vec x(0)=(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(3,0,1) \;\;\; \vec x'(0)=(x_1',x_2',x_3')=(0,0,0)$

I understand that one version is to make use of $p_i=x_i'$ making a new vector $\vec y =(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_1',x_2',x_3')$
$$\vec y'=A\vec y$$

But a $6×6$ matrix feels incredibly unpalletable for an exam. Any tips would be welcome.

Comment: I suggest asking your professor about what is he looking for in a solution. The matrix $A$ might be sparse actually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using Laplace transform methods. You'll have $3$ equations to solve for $X_1= \mathcal{L}\{x_1\}$, $X_2= \mathcal{L}\{x_2\}$, and $X_3= \mathcal{L}\{x_3\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Working out the answer given by @BobaFret:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{x}_1''\left(t\right)=\text{k}\cdot\left(\text{x}_2\left(t\right)-2\cdot\text{x}_1\left(t\right)\right)\\
\\
\text{x}_2''\left(t\right)=\text{k}\cdot\left(\text{x}_1\left(t\right)-2\cdot\text{x}_2\left(t\right)+\text{x}_3\left(t\right)\right)\\
\\
\text{x}_3''\left(t\right)=\text{k}\cdot\left(\text{x}_2\left(t\right)-2\cdot\text{x}_3\left(t\right)\right)
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

Now, for the Laplace transform of this system we get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{s}^2\cdot\text{X}_1\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{s}\cdot\text{x}_1\left(0\right)-\text{x}_1'\left(0\right)=\text{k}\cdot\left(\text{X}_2\left(\text{s}\right)-2\cdot\text{X}_1\left(\text{s}\right)\right)\\
\\
\text{s}^2\cdot\text{X}_2\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{s}\cdot\text{x}_2\left(0\right)-\text{x}_2'\left(0\right)=\text{k}\cdot\left(\text{X}_1\left(\text{s}\right)-2\cdot\text{X}_2\left(\text{s}\right)+\text{X}_3\left(\text{s}\right)\right)\\
\\
\text{s}^2\cdot\text{X}_3\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{s}\cdot\text{x}_3\left(0\right)-\text{x}_3'\left(0\right)=\text{k}\cdot\left(\text{X}_2\left(\text{s}\right)-2\cdot\text{X}_3\left(\text{s}\right)\right)
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Now, using the initial conditions:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{s}^2\cdot\text{X}_1\left(\text{s}\right)-3\cdot\text{s}=\text{k}\cdot\left(\text{X}_2\left(\text{s}\right)-2\cdot\text{X}_1\left(\text{s}\right)\right)\\
\\
\text{s}^2\cdot\text{X}_2\left(\text{s}\right)=\text{k}\cdot\left(\text{X}_1\left(\text{s}\right)-2\cdot\text{X}_2\left(\text{s}\right)+\text{X}_3\left(\text{s}\right)\right)\\
\\
\text{s}^2\cdot\text{X}_3\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{s}=\text{k}\cdot\left(\text{X}_2\left(\text{s}\right)-2\cdot\text{X}_3\left(\text{s}\right)\right)
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Solving each function out of its own equation:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{X}_1\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{k}\cdot\text{X}_2\left(\text{s}\right)+3\cdot\text{s}}{\text{s}^2+2\cdot\text{k}}\\
\\
\text{X}_2\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{k}\cdot\left(\text{X}_1\left(\text{s}\right)+\text{X}_3\left(\text{s}\right)\right)}{\text{s}^2+2\cdot\text{k}}\\
\\
\text{X}_3\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{k}\cdot\text{X}_2\left(\text{s}\right)+\text{s}}{\text{s}^2+2\cdot\text{k}}
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

Comment: I'm split between giving you or Boba the answer :( he was first after all but yours is way more detailed.